# Bash скрипт с Asterisk

Tags: mysql, bash

Нужно разобраться со скриптом:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date`
id=$(mysql -D asterisk -se "select marcatet,sender FROM notication WHERE marcatet <= 10");
echo "$DATE : Result : $id"

asterisk -rx "sip show peer $sender"
```

Ошибка:

> Fri Jun 26 20:47:32 EEST 2015 : Result : 2      1000

Usage: sip show peer  не ставится

Comment: 1. значение из поля `marcatet` действительно необходимо для чего-то? 2. а что должен сделать скрипт, если результат выполнения запроса вернёт несколько строк? 3. логин и пароль, наверно, ни к чему выкладывать на общее обозрение.

Comment: Спосибо за ответ, согласен поля marcatet не нужна. На самом деле скрипт проверяет баланс и должын делать asterisk -rx "dongle stop now $sender" где sender имя модемаб тоесть отключает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если значение из поля `marcatet` действительно не требуется, то остаётся разобраться с ситуацией, когда запрос вернёт более одной строки.

можно ограничить выдачу запроса одной строкой, примерно так:

```
id=$(mysql ... "select sender from notifications where marcatet <= 10 limit 1")
echo "$(date) : Result : $id"
asterisk -rx "sip show peer $id"
```

а можно в цикле вызывать `asterisk ...` для каждого из возвращённых значений `sender`-а, примерно так:

```
id=$(mysql ... "select sender from notifications where marcatet <= 10")
echo "$(date) : Result : $id"
for s in $id; do asterisk -rx "sip show peer $s"; done
```

Comment: Спосибо за ответ, запуск скрипта
Fri Jun 26 22:28:27 EEST 2015 : Result : 1000
2000
но срабатывет только для 1000

Comment: Скрипт работает правельно но на asterisk -rx "sip show peer $s"; к примеру реагировает только на один ответ. Есль id=$(mysql ... "select sender from notifications where marcatet <= 10")
echo "$(date) : Result : $id"
1000
2000
3000 ответ quere но asterisk -rx "sip show peer $s" реагировает на 1000 и все.

Comment: срабатывает *что*? астериск вызывается только один раз? а должен вызываться два раза? для теста замените `asterisk -rx "sip show peer $s"` на `echo $s`, после строки, начинающейся с даты, должно вернуться две строки, в первой `1000`, во второй `2000`

Comment: Да тест прошол удачно Fri Jun 26 22:37:18 EEST 2015 : Result : 1000
2000
1000 2000 оставалось разобраца с астериском. Спосьбо
Надо поставить then sleep 60 && asterisk -rx "sip show peer $s"

Comment: если тест прошёл успешно, попробуйте заменить цикл `while` на цикл `for` — я внёс исправление в ответ.

Comment: прошу прощения — были лишние кавычки вокруг `$id`, я внёс ещё одно исправление в ответ.

Comment: Заменил не работает видет только один ответ Peer 1000
2000 not found надо как было и поставеть then sleep 60

Comment: я уже написал: были лишние кавычки. я исправил ответ.

Comment: `then sleep 60` — это зачем?

Comment: alexander barakin, все работает.  Спосьбо вам большое

Comment: если ответ был полезен, отметьте его, пожалуйста, «галочкой» (слева от ответа).